# Upload files without using php but no php form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a **C program** running on the localhost server which **generates some files( writes its output to these file). Then I zip all these files together using php**. Now I want to upload the zip file produced to mysql server using some php script but i **dont want the user to upload these files using a form by clicking choose file button but i would like to upload these automatically as soon as they are generated to mysql using php script.**

```
<?php
 //get content of json file
 require_once("zip.php");
 $str = file_get_contents("program/heatmap_parameters.json");
 //decode the JSON
 $json = json_decode($str,true);
 //echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>';
 foreach ($json['parameters'] as $params) {
    echo $params[3]."<br>";
    $files_to_zip = array("program/".$params[3]);
    var_dump($files_to_zip)."<br>";
    //$files_to_zip = array("program/cctv2.mp4.json");
//if true, good; if false, zip creation failed
    $zip_name = "program/".$params[3].".zip";
    //zip the files
    $result = create_zip($files_to_zip,$zip_name);

 }
//connect to database
 require_once("database/conn.php");
//upload zip file to database without displaying any form.    

 ?>
```

I need a way to upload my generated file to saved to mysql without choosing it from the form.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="box">
    <tr> 
    <td width="246">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
    <input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile"> 
    </td>
    <td width="80"><input name="upload" type="submit" class="box" id="upload" value=" Upload "></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    include '../database/conn.php';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO upload (name, content ) ".
    "VALUES ('$fileName', '$content')";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if(!$query){
        die("Cannot Insert".mysql_error());
                }

}
```

How can i make this code such that it does not need the form

Comment: I think you were wrong with your wording. On So you ask with required code (the not working one). Then we can check it and help you to fix. We won't write code for you!

Comment: @LelioFaieta I don't need your help to fix the code as it is up and running nor I am asking to write down a 1000 lines code for me. I just need your help in solving the last problem.

Comment: I believe that after `create_zip()` you have the file available. Am I right?

Comment: yes it creates a zip file . Lets call it test.zip and I now the path to it (lets say /var/www/html/test.zip )

Comment: @DeepakSRautela then what's your issue? You want to put the file (be it link, name, or just plain data) into a MySQL database. Your current steps lead to creating the file, you know its name, you know its location, yet you fail to send it to MySQL? How is that possible? You have all the information you need, or did I misunderstand something in the question?

Comment: @ROAL I have updated the problem you may get more clearity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question in oneline,

> You can not upload a file without form/input type file element, because that will a big security hole to web.

To upload any file to server, server need files object which has all the info of file. that info will be given by client from where you are uploading a file. It will also has the tmp location of file form where server will take that file.

> You can copy file from one server to another, using curl or you can
>   write a bash script which will copy file from one place to another and
>   you can run that bash script using PHP.

Hope this helps to you!

Comment: Thanks. I will try this but if the php script is on my own localhost server, the files to be uploaded are also on my own localhost then why can't that script access my files and why does a submit button is required.

Comment: LIke I explain in answer, when you upload any file it takes file info from client only, that info contains headers and main thing is file origin. 
Submit button is not needed since you can submit form using javascript as well. When you select file using browse button, in php $_FILE variable gets all the information file and only that way it gets uploaded. In your case, you are trying to achieve is copying file from one location to another. Hence there are ways to do that in PHP but that is not uploading.